# Compare two arrays and print out Index of row in python

Tags: python, numpy, compare

I have two arrays A and B

```
A = np.array([[9, 10, 11, 12.0],[13 14 15 16.3]])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16],[17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

I want to compare a couple of the elements of A[:,2:4] with couple elements of B[:,2:4] and print out the rows where they are equal or approximate?
Here is my approach just for only **A[:,3]**

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16.3]])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16],[17, 18, 19, 20]])
for k in range(0,A.shape[0]):
    i = np.where(np.isclose(B[:,3], A[k,3], atol=0.5))
    print (i)
```

How can I do it with both **A[:,2]** and **A[:,3]** ?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show us your expected output ?

Comment: A[:,2:4] and B[:,3] are not broadcastable, so let me ask you what your expected output would be here

Comment: @MSS Of course, the expected output should be i=2 and i=3

Comment: @Alai the code above just only compares one value. For ex, I saw A[0,3]=12 in B[2,3] so I print out i=2. 

But my propose is: If A[0,3] = B[2,3] and A[0,2] = B[2,2] i will print out i=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np

indexes_to_compare = range(2,4)
A = np.array([[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16.3]])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16],[17, 18, 19, 20]])

for a in A:
    print(np.where(np.all(np.isclose(B[:,indexes_to_compare], a[indexes_to_compare], atol=0.5), axis=1))[0])
```

You compare `B` with each row of `A`, taking into consideration only few indexes.

Thus you:

- Check if `B` is close to a row of `A` (in selected indexes) with `np.isclose(_)`
- Keep only rows where **all** selected indexes are close, with `np.all(_, axis=1)`
- Get index of such rows with `np.where`

If you want to make sure to only output one row of `B` per cycle, just use `np.where(_)[0][0]`